# Unable to display error message hint for a validation in a simple_form of the rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, simple-form, error-messaging

```
1. validates :note, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6, maximum: 140 }
```

this would show fine in my simple_form by displaying "`too short!`" or "`too long!`" error messages hint right below the entry field.

```
2. validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:year, :month, :day], message: "one person only allow one entry every day" }
```

form code:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@worktime) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :note, label: false, as: :text, placeholder: 'please comment here' %>
    <%= f.submit 'submit' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

this would show in a regular form, but not in my simple_form, I do not know why?

Thanks a lot in advance!

`Ruby 2.3.3, rails 5.0.1`

Comment: Can you please add the code of your simple_form ?

Comment: <%= simple_form_for(@worktime) do |f| %>
  
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">

    <%= f.input :note, label: false, as: :text, placeholder: 'please comment here' %>
   
    <%= f.submit 'submit' %>
  </div>
  
<% end %>

Comment: hm.. where is the `user_id` field? :O do you set the `user` for `@worktime` in the controller? `simple_form` will add the error under the related field, and since you don't have a field for the `user_id`, well... you get it.... anyway, you probably don't want to have a `user_id` field in the form but you can print the `@worktime.errors.full_messages` i guess, check it out

Comment: <%= simple_form_for(@worktime) do |f| %>
  
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
  
   <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
    <%= f.input :note, label: false, as: :text, placeholder: 'at least 6 words, maximum 140' %>
   
    <%= f.submit 'submit' %>
  </div>

<% end %>

Comment: the simple form works fine by updating database correctly. I have had a user_id, and forgot to included it here. It only did not handle validation error message very well automatically. I think I have a trouble to understand how simple form work inside of how a customized error message really works.